# How can I make dynamic functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, dynamic-function

I have 10 functions like these:

```
function instagram_ajax(){
    return ajaxRequest('search/instagramid', 'instagramid').then(
        function(res) {
            var imgStatus = res[1].length > 0 ? "checked_successfully.png" : "checked_noRes.png";
            $('.option_name_instagramid + td').html("<img src='img/" + imgStatus + "' />")

            optionsRes['instagramid'] = res[1];

        }, function(err){
            $('.option_name_instagramid + td').html("<img src='img/warning.png' />")
        }
    );
}

function googleplus_ajax(){
    return ajaxRequest('search/googleplusid', 'googleplusid').then(
        function(res) {
            var imgStatus = res[1].length > 0 ? "checked_successfully.png" : "checked_noRes.png";
            $('.option_name_googleplusid + td').html("<img src='img/" + imgStatus + "' />")

            optionsRes['googleplusid'] = res[1];

        }, function(err){
            $('.option_name_googleplusid + td').html("<img src='img/warning.png' />")
        }
    );
}

.
.
.
```

As you see, those functions are almost equivalent, just the difference is words `instagram`, `googleplus`. Also I have an array of all those names:

```
var parts = ['instagram', 'googleplus', 'linkedin', 'facebook', ...];
```

Now I want to know, is it possible to make those array dynamically? I mean by putting a variable-base function into a loop and use that array to make all those functions? Is such a thing possible?

Comment: It's quite possible, just pass the variables as parameters to the functions and make a loop for each item in your array, calling the same function with the different parameter

Comment: Just a correction: one passes an *argument*, not a parameter. A parameter never changes, an argument does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a wrappper function

```
function ajax(str) {
  return function() {
    return ajaxRequest('search/'+str+'id', ''+str+'id').then(
        function(res) {
            var imgStatus = res[1].length > 0 ? "checked_successfully.png" : "checked_noRes.png";
            $('.option_name_'+str+'id + td').html("<img src='img/" + imgStatus + "' />")

            optionsRes[str+'id'] = res[1];

        }, function(err){
            $('.option_name_'+str+'id + td').html("<img src='img/warning.png' />")
        }
    );
  }
}

var instagram_ajax = ajax('instagram');
var googleplus_ajax = ajax('googleplus');
```

or for your case

```
var parts = ['instagram', 'googleplus', 'linkedin', 'facebook'];

var funcs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
  funcs[parts[i]] = ajax(parts[i]);

// now u do
funcs.instagram()
```

Comment: I just don't understand this line `funcs.instagram(...params)`. what's that for?